# Radio buttons result show on body onload in show/hide div

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

This shows result on selected radio button. I have a problem, when the page is refreshed no div shows and no result displays.  I want show the Carsbuy div on page refresh.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[name$='mode']").click(function() {
            var test = $(this).val();

            $("div.desc").hide();
            $("#Cars" + test).show();
        });
    });

<input type="radio" name="mode" checked="checked" value="buy"  />

<label>Buy</label>

<input type="radio" name="mode" value="rent" />

<Label>Rent</label>

<div id="Carsbuy" class="desc" style="display: none;">

    Buy Cars Result Display Here On Select Buy

</div>

<div id="Carsrent" class="desc" style="display: none;">

    Rent Cars Result Display Here On Select Rent
</div>
```

Comment: it not display result on body on load plz check ur edited code @NAVEED

Comment: can you please explain what are you asking for... i cannot understand your language properly, you want to display the `div` on load or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following at the beginning of your js code to shoe specific DIV on page load:

```
$("#Carsbuy").show();
```

**Edit:**

for a specific DIV and radio button, use following:

```
var selected = 'rent';
$("div.desc").hide();
$("#Cars" + selected).show();
$('input[value="' + selected + '"]').attr('checked', true);
```

You can change the value of `var selected` to select a specific radio button and DIV

## Demo

Comment: ok now i want to show selected button after page refresh . i mean if a select rent and refresh page it show be rent on page refresh ?

Comment: naveed its not work on local you can test your code on local .just working on http://jsfiddle.net . test it plz

Comment: Remember you have to place your all code in `$(document).ready(function() { });` function including my code in answer.

Comment: WORking Perfect Now thanx @naveed

Answer (score 0):

As much i understand your requirement, you can do it as below.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" name="mode" checked="checked" value="buy"  />
<label>Buy</label>
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="rent" />
<Label>Rent</label>
<div id="CarsDetails" class="desc">
  // include buy type cars initialy while page load.
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() { // detect when radio button is clicked
     var carType = $(this).val(); // get the value of selected radio type
     $.ajax({
      url : "cartype.php", // link to file containing data of cars
      type : "GET",  // request type
      data : "carType="+carType,  // send the selected car type (buy or rent)
      datatype : "html",
      success : function(response){  // get the response
            $('#CarsDetails').html(response);  // put the response in div.
      }
     });
   });
});
```

Comment: didnt get you..?? which form and button you are talking about ?? please be more descriptive. also check the fiddle i have given in answer.

Comment: i have a search form in which search rent and buy cars . now i want if i search rent cars rent will checked on subitted search form ..you understand ?

Comment: yeah understood.. so you are populating using ajax right, you can do that inside ajax on success handler.

Comment: I understood your requirement and updated the answer accordingly. this is a very easy way to do. you dont need two div for it and you dont need to refresh page everytime user click on readio button.

Answer (score 0):

In the following code ,on page load check if a radio button is selected then its appropriate div is displayed . If condition is used to prevent if no radio button is selected

```
$(document).ready(function()   {
var selected =  $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();

if(selected !== 'undefined')
{
   $("#Cars" + selected ).show();
}

$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").attr('id')
    $("input[name$='mode']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();

        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#Cars" + test).show();
    });
});
```